# Compression fails with PageSpeed Insights using Azure CDN

Tags: azure, cdn, google-pagespeed

I'm using PageSpeed Insight and sometimes says that I have to compress files, I'm using Azure CDN an I've enabled compression using the following link,

So, I'm a little confused because I have no idea why is working random

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-improve-performance/

Comment: I found the same issue. The compression is configured for the Azure CDN, I even added text/javascript MIME type, but it didn't help :/